# Unevaluated chunk in knitr generates a line break

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

The following `Rnw` file produces the output shown below. Is there a clean way to prevent the line break in section 2? 
Of course, this is just a minimal reproducible example; I don't want to remove the unevaluated chunk, which is programatically evaluated or not in my real issue.

```
\documentclass{article}

<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
@

\begin{document}

\section{eval TRUE}

<<results='asis'>>=
cat("Hello.")
@
<<eval=TRUE, results='asis'>>=
cat("How are you?")
@
What's your name?


\section{eval FALSE}

<<results='asis'>>=
cat("Hello.")
@
<<eval=FALSE, results='asis'>>=
cat("How are you?")
@
What's your name?

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

I have one solution so far:

```
<<results='asis'>>=
cat("Hello.")
if(FALSE) cat("How are you?")
@
What's your name?
```

But I'm wondering whether there's a simpler one, which does not require to group the chunks in a single one like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, regardless of all options, `knitr` apparently prints at least a newline for each chunk (even if `eval = FALSE, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"`). Therefore, the following is just a workaround, but probably a cleaner workaround than the one in the question:

Use `if` in the chunk (in lieu of the chunk option `eval`) but print `%` if the chunk is not supposed to be evaluated. This will make TEX ignore the line.

```
\documentclass{article}

<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
  knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
  showIt <- FALSE
@

\begin{document}

\section{eval FALSE}

<<results='asis'>>=
  cat("Hello.")
@
<<results='asis'>>=
  if(showIt) {
    cat("How are you?")
  } else {
    cat("%")
  }
@
What's your name?

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, not a bad idea. I doubt we can do better so I accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent You could try to file a bug report / feature request. Maybe Yihui can help you …